# Grunt Connect requires .html extension

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I have been building a site with Grunt and grunt-contrib-connect.

I would like to have my site urls not require file extensions (i.e. 'foo' not 'foo.html')
From what I can gather gunt-contrib-connect does not pay attention to htaccess files so I can't define a mod rewrite there.

This seems to be possible with the use of middleware but I can't find any mention of how this is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                base: 'build/',
                livereload: true,
                open: true
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to the connect middleware to implement the rewrite rules, according to the [connect documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#middleware).

The grunt-connect-rewrite seems like the way to go you can find more information here: https://github.com/viart/grunt-connect-rewrite.

Here's the exact same question using the before mentioned implementation.

[Removing file extension using grunt-contrib-connect and grunt-connect-rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422559/removing-file-extension-using-grunt-contrib-connect-and-grunt-connect-rewrite)